# What is an idiomatic and fast class for objects that can be rendered to screen?

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, game-engine

My game has very particular graphics that don't fit the GPU workflow, so I'm doing the rendering on CPU by storing the screen as an unboxed vector:

```
type Pixel = Word32
data Image = Image { size :: V2 Int, buffer :: U.Vector Pixel }
```

With this, I need a class for objects that can be rendered on screen. The naive solution would be:

```
class Renderable obj where
    -- Receives the object, the render position, and the image.
    render :: obj -> V2 Int -> Image -> Image
```

But, obviously, since `render` will copy the whole image, this approach is unpractical to render hundreds of objects per frame. A more efficient solution is is `render :: obj -> V2 Int -> [(V2 Int, Pixel)]` - that is, instead of actually rendering, you build a list of pixels to be rendered. The `draw loop` then just concats those lists and render all in a single pass using [unboxed vector's bulk updates](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:update).

This is still not ideal, though: allocating and concatenating those lists can be costly (imagine objects with 128x128 pixels), whereas in usual languages you'd have a mutable function with no costs. To get the maximum performance, you could use something like: `render :: (PrimMonad m) => obj -> V2 Int -> MVector (PrimState m) -> IO ()` - that is, render operates directly in a mutable vector. The draw loop could call this function directly and no allocation would occur. But that would make writing `render` cumbersome.

Is there any idiomatic approach that combines the efficiency of the last version with the simplicity of the former versions?

Answer (score 1):

If most of your objects doesn't overlap, then you can build a vector of patches for all renderable objects (each patch is an image covering only the object, plus its position in the final image) and then use `Data.Vector.Unboxed.generate` to produce the final image. The function in `generate` will look for the topmost visible patch for particular pixel position. In that case you are allocating a lot of small vectors, but the total memory used will be comparable to memory use of the final image (remember that object doesn't usually overlap.)

It objects overlap, then you can cut their images to not overlapping pieces.

(But really there is nothing wrong with mutable implementation :) )